# How to handle duplicate items coming from an external JSON API and being imported as article content

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, joomla-api, json

I have adapted working code from Joomla 3 and the CLI to Joomla 4/5 and the API. The core functionality using the API system is working, but I am struggling to find a replacement for checking for duplicate aliases.

When a duplicate article alias is encountered, Joomla/Admin Tools send the following message via email: `Message: Save failed with the following error: Another Article in this category has the same alias.` This message is issued numerous times depending on how many news items are being imported. The max importation is set to `10` for individual requests. Requests are made once a day in the early morning via a cron job.

The external JSON API provides is a news source that has unique titles for individual items, but no aliases beyond the article's href element. I have included a sample snippet of a news item below for reference.

```
{
  "id": "18d02c72-7206-4a6a-bec1-0f608524c422__4086381",
  "links": {
    "article": {
      "href": "/publishing/news/articles/18d02c72-7206-4a6a-bec1-0f608524c422__4086381"
    }
  },
  "title": "DTN Closing Livestock Comments",
  "subTitle": "Markets Stabilized Friday Following Bearish Weak",
  "storySummary": "<span class=\"news_summary_content\">Limited buyer support trickled into livestock trade Friday, attempting to bring some sense of stability to a tumbling cattle market. Despite moderate support midday, live cattle contracts closed mixed with continued concerns of longer-term support. It is unlikely that the weekend will bring much clarity to livestock markets.</span>",
  "publishDate": "2023-11-10T21:56:00Z",
  "product": null,
  "author": {
    "name": "Rick Kment"
  },
  "thumbNailImage": {
    "name": "2020closinglivestock.jpg",
    "imageUrl": "https://www.dtnpf.com/mydtn-public-core-portlet/servlet/GetStoredImage?category=CMS&symbolicName=2020closinglivestock.jpg",
    "caption": "(DTN file photo)"
  },
  "cmsCategoryId": null,
  "dtnpfUrl": "https://www.dtnpf.com/agriculture/web/ag/news/article/2023/11/10/markets-stabilized-friday-following",
  "language": "en",
  "topic": "DTN/Ag/Livestock",
  "content": "<span class=\"news_summary_content\">Limited buyer support trickled into livestock trade Friday, attempting to bring some sense of stability to a tumbling cattle market. Despite moderate support midday, live cattle contracts closed mixed with continued concerns of longer-term support. It is unlikely that the weekend will bring much clarity to livestock markets.</span>",
  "status": null,
  "audioLinks": null,
  "mediaLinks": null
}
```

Here is the code that was previously used in the CLI for handling duplicate aliases. As this code utilizes the Joomla database, I do not think it could be used for the API.

```
private function removeDuplicateAliases(array $articles): array {
  $db = Factory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query
    ->select('a.alias')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid') . " = " . $db->quote('13'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $aliasLookup = array_flip($db->loadColumn());

  foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
    if (isset($aliasLookup[OutputFilter::stringURLSafe($article->title)])) {
      unset($articles[$i]);
    }
  }
  return $articles;
}
```

The function was run within the insertArticles function `foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article)`.

Here is the working API-based code for the retrieval and processing of the external JSON API:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

$dataSourceUrl = Redacted;

$processArticles = function ($articles) {
  foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $data = [
      'id' => 0,
      'catid' => 13,
      'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
      'articletext' => $article->content,
      'introtext' => $article->storySummary,
      'fulltext' => $article->content,
      'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
      'state' => 1,
      'access' => 1,
      'created_by' => 386,
      'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
      'language' => '*',
    ];
    $articleData = json_encode($data);

    $apiUrl = Redacted;
    $token = Redacted;

    // Request timeout
    $timeOut = 10;

    $headers = [
      'Accept: application/vnd.api+json',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Content-length: ' . mb_strlen($articleData),
      sprintf('X-Joomla-Token: %s', trim($token)),
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => sprintf('%s/%s', $apiUrl, 'content/articles'),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'utf-8',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeOut,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $articleData,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
      ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($response === false) {
      echo 'CURL error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    } else {
      curl_close($curl);
    }
  }
};

$generator = function (string $dataSourceResponse): Generator {
  if (empty($dataSourceResponse)) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'DTN API response must not be empty', 422 );
  }

  if ($data === false) {
    yield new RuntimeException( 'Could not read response', 500 );
  }

  try {
  } finally {
    echo 'Done processing data' . PHP_EOL;
  }
};

$process = function (string $dataSourceUrl, string $dataString) {
  $curlOptions = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $dataSourceUrl,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $dataString,
  ];
  $transport = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($transport, $curlOptions);
  $data = curl_exec($transport);

  if (empty($data)) {
    throw new RuntimeException( 'Empty output', 422 );
  }

  return json_decode($data);
};

$dataSourceDataString = '';

try {
  $dataSourceResponse = $process($dataSourceUrl, $dataSourceDataString);
  $displayData        = $processArticles($dataSourceResponse);
} finally {
}
```

The above still needs to be refined and may include some code that could be redundant and could be removed.

I have been using this [Joomla 4 API example as reference](https://github.com/alexandreelise/j4x-api-examples/blob/master/using-raw-php/turn-your-top-5-favorite-movies-into-joomla-articles-omdb-api.php) for completing the migration from the J3 CLI to the J4/5 API system.